# Deleting a row from database and getting the id value of each row in another class

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I want to delete a row from the database. I added the row to the listview and when I press the delete button, only the row gets deleted from the listview but not from database. I have my database in another class. I want to access the id value of the database in my another class in which I have the listview and delete button so as to fire the delete query. So how can I pass the id value of each row to another class? Here is my code I am using to delete a row from listview:

```
Button btnRemove = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
btnRemove.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
btnRemove.setFocusable(false);
btnRemove.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               results.remove(position);
               notifyDataSetChanged();
           }
});
```

I have this code in myadapter class. My database is in another class, so to delete a row from db I need the id value. So how can I get the id value from that class to this class? This class extends Arrayadapter. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
results.remove(position); is deleting the item from your list only...
```

you need to get the id on click over list item and call `db's delete` method with that id ...

Comment: ya i know but i m not getting how to get the id .pls help me pls thanks

Comment: when you fetch data from db, save corresponding id.check this tutorial:http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: ya i saved it but how do i pass it in another class from which i m deleting

Comment: get the class object and call it's delete function which you are using to delete the row..

Comment: thanx frnd i did that. the function gets called but the db is coming null. how to pass the db from sqliteopenhelper to my activity in which i m displaying the listview. pls help